# Accelerate framerate for figure update in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, video, frame-rate

I read in a video in MATLAB like this:

```
v = VideoReader('testvid.wmv')

cnt = 0;
while hasFrame(v)
    cnt = cnt + 1;
    video(cnt,:,:,:) = readFrame(v);
end
```

If I check out the video object, I tells me that the video is with 24 frames.
However, If would show it directly after reading it (so basically `imshow(readframe(v))` inside the for-loop it only gets shown with around 5 frames per second.

That's why I have written it like the code above, so that the frames are getting prestored into the workspace, and now I can show them like

```
figure
for i=1:cnt
   tic
   imshow(squeeze(video(i,:,:,:)))
   toc
end
```

However, I still get only 10 frames - is MATLAB limitied in this direction? Is there a better way to display a video with a fast enough framerate inside MATLAB?

Comment: There are 24 frames per "second", as in the video will play that fast played in a video player. As you know, MATLAB is not a video player, so it will plot stuff as fast as it can. You are not reproducing a video actually, you are telling MATLAB "display these images one by one as fast as you can". If you had a powerful computer, it may even display them faster than 24/s.

Comment: One thing you could do though would be to make MATLAB open VLC to read your movie file. see the [system](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html?refresh=true) command if you want to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update your plot CData rather than replotting it every time.

```
% Prepare 24 fake RGB coloured frames
A = randn(100,100,3,24);

figure

% Time the frame display time when replotting
tic
for k = 1 : 24
     h = imshow(A(:,:,:,k));
     drawnow
end
t = toc;
disp(t / 24)


% Time the frame display time when updating CData
tic
for k = 1 : 24
    if k == 1
        % Create the image object
        h = imshow(A(:,:,:,k));
    else
       % Update the Cdata property of image
       set(h , 'cdata' , A(:,:,:,k));
    end
    drawnow
end
t = toc;
disp(t / 24)
```

My output is:

> ```
> 0.0854
>
> 0.0093
> ```

So I get a tenfold improvement when updating CData. This is actually faster than 24 frames per second!